# ARM Architecture Initialization

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture

In the case of x86 the same (real mode) bootloader works on virtually any x86 device.
Is that possible on ARM or do I need to create a specific bootloader for each 'cortex'?

Comment: There is popular u-boot - Das Universal Boot Loader: http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot. What is your target device? Many SoC with cortex implementations use uboot. (And modern x86 has UEFI which is not your parent's MBR, which itself is not bootloader, but only small part of boot loading process written on HDD, and most of boot controlled by BIOS and POST.) https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Bootloader lists some proprietary (locked) bootloaders of android platforms.

Answer (score 1):

x86 or lets say PC compatible systems are ... pc compatible.  They support the ancient bios calls so that there is massive compatibility.  by design, by the chip vendor (intel) the software vendors (bios, operating system) and the motherboard vendors.

ARM is in now way shape or form like that.  There are instruction sets you can choose that work almost or all the way across, but remember ARM systems you buy an ARM core and add it to your special chip, you and your special/custom stuff, then that is put on one or more different boards.  There is little to no compatibility.  Instruction set and arm core is a small part of the whole picture most of the code is for the non-arm stuff.

u-boot and perhaps others are fairly massive bootloaders, pretty much an operating system themselves, and have to be ported just like an operating system to each chip/board combination.  The chip vendor, if this is a linux compatible system, most likely has a reference design and a BSP including a u-boot port and/or some other solution (rasberry pi is a good example).  it is fairly trivial to boot linux or used to be, there is no reason for the massively overcomplicated u-boot.  without a DTB you setup a few memory locations a register or two and branch to the kernel, thats it (again look at the raspberry pi), I assume with DTB you build the dtb then put it somewhere, setup a few registers and branch to the linux kernel (raspberry pi?  ntc chip?)

Comment: Thank you im interested in learning the cortex a15 on qemu it would be great im you can show me a minimal bootloader written in gcc assembly

Comment: cortex a15 has little to do with it, chip and board matter as much as core, yo cannot have a single cortex a15 bootloader for all of the cortex a15 chip and board combinations, you have to pick a specific cortex a15 on a specific board then have a discussion about that.  which is beyond what stackoverflow is about anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Arm open source project that can cover Armv7/v8 Cortex-A processors bootloaders.

- https://git.trustedfirmware.org/TF-A/trusted-firmware-a.git/

Another open source project for Cortex-M processors:

- https://git.trustedfirmware.org/TF-M/trusted-firmware-m.git/